# Needs a helping hand setting up a kik bot with python

Tags: bots, kik

I need some help setting up a bot.   I'm really newbie in this not
familiar alot with python but I am with perl and php.

a. I created a bot thru the kik 
b. I ran pip install kik on my server 
c. I created the test code

```
        requests.post(
            'https://api.kik.com/v1/config',
            auth=('', ''),
            headers={
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data=json.dumps({
                "webhook": "https://example.com/incoming",
                "features": {
                    "manuallySendReadReceipts": False,
                    "receiveReadReceipts": False,
                    "receiveDeliveryReceipts": False,
                    "receiveIsTyping": False
                }
            })
    )
```

I filled in username, api key and I created a web hook to a test script in perl that prints hello world.

What do I work with the above code?

How do I run it on the server.  Does it have to be continually running and if so how.

Also on my server its running python 2.6.  Is that ok.

Thank-you
David
**strong text**

Comment: What program are you using for your server?

Comment: Centos Linux Server, python 2.6 is installed. I installed pip then installed kik package.   ran my test script above from the command line but came back with errors thats why I'm thinking maybe the wrong version of python.

Also I'm not sure how to make the script above poll kik from server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

I added at the beginning of the code:

import requests;
import json;